# How to show string characters on tap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, sprite-kit

Say I have a string and an SKLableNode

```
NSString *testString = @"Hello world, this is a test";
SKLableNode *label;
label.text = testString;
```

How do I make it so that every time I tap, the label would show a little more of the testString? For example, the label will be empty at first and it will show the following when the screen is tapped.

first tap: "Hello world,"
second tap: "Hello world, this is"
third tap: "Hello world, this is a test"

Comment: Use (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange. Use an int as a counter to update your range.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add a view above the `SKLabelNode`. Then add a gesture recognizer to the label and alter its `text` property on tap.

Answer (score 0):

there is no real way to do it. The only i can think of is to have 3 differnet strings, and every time someone taps the button it shows a different string. Like this...

var number of times
var string1 = "hello world"

var string2 = "hello world, that is"

var string3 = "hello world, that is a test"

Answer (score 0):

You could take a couple of approaches to do this. You could create an object to hold the `testString` in question as well as the amount of exposure. Where the "amount of exposure" indicates how much of the string to show. This could be by percentage, by number of characters, etc. If by percentage, just remember to round by actual number of characters.

Upon a tap, update the amount of exposure.This in turn would update the `SKLabel`'s text field.

Another way you could also do it is by using a mask. This would be useful if you didn't care if you partially showed part of a character. You'd still need to manage the "amount of exposure".

Example class to do this.

```
@interface ExposedText : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *fullString;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *exposedString; // This will indicate the exposed string
@property (nonatomic, assign) float amountExposed; // This is to set your exposure amount, in this case it's a %
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKLabel *label; // This is the reference to the label this object will modify, IF you want this object to update the label directly

- (void)increaseExposure:(float)increaseAmt; // Example method to increase the amount, likewise, you could have a customer getter for amountExposed and just use that

@end
```

I have not defined what an `init` variant would look like.

The gist is that this class knows how to "expose" the appropriate amount of the string. You'd have to determine the algorithm for this. `fullString` would be your full string. In your case `"Hello world, this is a test"`. If say exposureAmt was 0.5 (50%), `exposedString` would return `"Hello world, "`. You could either have this class directly update the `SKLabel` (which is why I had it as a property). Or you could have other code use the instance of this class and update the `SKLabel`.

Note if you went for the mask route (`SKCropNode`) and you wanted the class to update it, you'd have to add the appropriate properties, etc.